# Error while creating new react app (You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).)

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, web-deployment, npx

(I am using ubuntu.)

**the message i am getting:**

You are running `create-react-app` 5.0.0, which is behind the latest release (5.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/

I have already tried:
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npx clean-npx-cache
npx create-react-app@latest project-name

**Nothing works**

what should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late but...

I also had the same problem and every solution I found didn't seem to work. In the end I found it out.

I have both yarn and npm installed
create-react-app was installed in both and they were referencing each other

**You need to perform both if you have both yarn and npm**

- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

Then clear cache using one (or both)

- npx clear-npx-cache
- npm cache clean -f

Then run to install and create the app

- npx create-react-app@latest your-app-name

Hope it helps someone :)